# Qual a diferença entre CssClass="exemplo" e class="exemplo"

Tags: css, asp.net, aspx

Me deparei com o seguinte trecho de código:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblStatus" CssClass="labelFiltro" runat="server" Text="Status:"></asp:Label>
```

Até então eu não conhecia `CssClass`, gostaria de saber qual é a diferença dele para somente `class` e se o modo como definimos o estilo é diferente, exemplo:

```
/* O exemplo abaixo funcionaria para ambos? */
.labelFiltro {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Acho que é parâmetro do .Net pra ele identificar como uma classe css na hora do parse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na prática não há nenhuma diferença.

[**`CssClass`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass(v=vs.110).aspx) é uma propriedade dos [controles *web* do ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass(v=vs.110).aspx) — muito usado em projetos *WebForms*, não tenho certeza se existe outro caso em que eles são usados.

Ele é apenas um *wrapper* abstrato para o atributo `class` do HTML que tem como objetivo renderizar para o atributo **`class`**.

Ou seja: se você usar a propriedade como `CssClass="exemplo"`, o HTML gerado será `class="exemplo"`.

Talvez você não tenha entendido o propósito dela por estar escrevendo o código diretamente no arquivo de *design*, mas entenda que por ser uma propriedade do controle, ela é manipulável através de qualquer lugar do seu código, ou seja, é possível alterar a classe CSS mesmo estando no *code-behind*.

Answer (score 3):

A diferença é que o primeiro é tratado no servidor, enquanto que o segundo é atributo resultado do primeiro e tratado no cliente.

`CssClass` é uma propriedade de controle de estilo rodada no servidor com framework .NET e renderizada no cliente como atributo `class`. O resultado é um elemento HTML com a `class` especificada no `CssClass`.

O resultado de `<asp:Label ID="lblStatus" CssClass="labelFiltro" runat="server" Text="Status:"></asp:Label>` seria:

```
<label id="lblStatus" class="labelFiltro">Status</label>
```

O código abaixo citado irá aplicar normalmente os estilos da classe `labelFiltro` ao elemento HTML:

```
.labelFiltro {
  color: blue;
}
```